# how to get nth term of series 2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,

Tags: math, numbers

I want to get nth term of the sequence of binary numbers with only two set bits in increasing order

```
(11,101,110,1001,1010,1100,10001,10010,10100,11000....).
```

I figured out it can be formed with string manipulation if I know the nth term of this series below:

> (2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6.....).

Can someone help me with how to get nth term of series:

> (2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6.....)

Edit: please focus to get the nth term of series only (2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6.....). I have other parts figured out.

Comment: please describe what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Setu i am stuck trying to get the nth term of (2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6.....). did not came much to my mind

Comment: I don't understand how these two sequences are alike. The sequence of binary numbers with only 2 bits set is [`{3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20, 24, ...}`](https://oeis.org/A018900).

Comment: if I want to know the 6th term of first sequence (lets call a) then i check 6th term of second sequence(lets call b) which is 4. so i know 6th term(lets call ans) of a has 4 chars with leftmost char=1 and that's the 1st 4 in sequence b, so the 1st char from left of x will be 1 and others chars will be 0. hence 6th term of a will be 1001

Comment: Please check basic facts on the sequence of triangle or triangular numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: @Pang I agree, this problem came from a programming question but basically it is a math problem. how to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are C(N,1)=N combinations of length N, starting with 1 and containing 2 ones.
So you have one 2, two 3s, three fours and so on - note arithmetic progression. Another point of view: we can see the first

```
2: at the 1st place
3: 2nd
4: 4th
5: 7
6: 11
k: (k-1)*(k-2)/2 + 1   //from arithmetic progression sum formula
```

So solve quadratic equation

```
 N = (k-1) * (k-2) / 2 + 1
 or
 k^2 - 3 * k + 4 - 2 * N  = 0
```

for unknown k  - find positive root floored down to integer and you will get k as number at the n-th place in sequence

```
 D = 9 - 16 + 8 * N = 8*N - 7
 k = Floor((3 + Sqrt(8*N - 7)) / 2)
 example: for N=7   k = (3+Sqrt(56-7))/2 = 5
          for N=10  k = Floor(3+Sqrt(80-7))/2 = Floor(5.77) = 5
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last part after solving the quadratic equation

Comment: Thank you, i understand now :)

Comment: Note that alternative answer formula gives wrong answer for every first number in series (n=1,2,4,7,10...) - perhaps due to unusual ceiling rules

Answer (score 2):

This is [series A003057](http://oeis.org/A003057) at oeis.org.

There are several formulae that can be used to calculate the *n*th value. The simplest appears to be as follows:

```
a(n) = ceiling((sqrt(8n-7)+1)/2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do they formulate this?

Comment: @RajaDorji I don't know exactly how this formula is derived, but consider the sequence as a triangle of numbers with `2` at the top, `3 3` in the second row, `4 4 4` in the third, and so on. The number of the row in which the `n`th element occurs will be somewhere in the order of `√n / 2`, since the triangle can be thought of as a half-filled square.